# Difficulty with a Fourier Transform

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, continuous-signals, fourier, transform

What would be the best way to take the Fourier transform of
$$
f(t)\cdot \cos\big(\pi(t-1)\big)
$$
I'm aware that when you take the Fourier Transform of $\cos(kt)$ you get two impulse at the location of $k$. And that the $(t-1)$ would create a complex exponential. But you can only apply the time-shift when both functions are time shifted (at least to my knowledge at least). Really the $\pi$ and the non-time shifted $f(t)$ are really throwing me off. Thanks!

Comment: It could be useful to rewrite $f(t)\cos(\pi(t-1))$ using Euler's formula; $\cos(x)=(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2$. What happens to the Fourier transform then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to see that using the trigonometric identity in Equation $(1)$ below
$$
\cos(\theta_1 \pm \theta_2) = \cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2) \mp \sin(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2) \tag{1}
$$
We have
\begin{align}
f(t)\cos\big(\pi(t - 1)\big) &= f(t)\overbrace{\cos(\pi t - \pi)}^{\text{use Equation}\ (1)}\\
&\equiv -f(t)\cos(\pi t)\tag{2}
\end{align}
Which can be rewritten as
$$
-f(t)\cos(\pi t) = -f(t)\cos\left(2\pi \frac t2\right) = -f(t)\cos(2\pi f_c t)\quad\text{where}\quad f_c = \frac 12 
$$
And we know the Fourier cosine modulation frequency-shift property in equation $(3)$:
$$
\mathcal F\big\{x(t)\cos(2\pi f_c t)\big\} = \frac 12\big[X\left(f - f_c\right) + X\left(f + f_c\right)\big]\tag{3}
$$
You can now easily use Equation $(2)$ and $(3)$ to find the solution.

Comment: i most def forgot about that trig identity. i will try that. thank you!

Comment: You’re welcome. If this answers your question, remember to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

We have signal $y(t) = f(t)cos(\pi t-\pi)$. You are modulating amplitude where bias is $\pi$. By using Euler's formula you can rewrite singal as:
$$
y(t) = f(t)\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{j(\pi t - \pi)} + e^{-j(\pi t - \pi)}\right)
$$
$$
y(t) = \frac{1}{2}f(t)e^{j(\pi t - \pi)} + \frac{1}{2}f(t)e^{-j(\pi t - \pi)}
$$
$$
y(t) = \frac{1}{2}f(t)e^{j\pi t}e^{-j\pi}  + \frac{1}{2}f(t)e^{-j\pi t}e^{j\pi}
$$
And then by Fourier transform we get :
$$
Y(j\omega) = \frac{1}{2}F(j(\omega -\pi))e^{-j\pi} + \frac{1}{2}F(j(\omega+\pi))e^{j\pi}
$$
$$
Y(j\omega) = -\frac{1}{2}F(j(\omega -\pi))  -\frac{1}{2}F(j(\omega+\pi))
$$
And we get this becuase $e^{-j\pi}=-1$ and $e^{j\pi}=-1$